How to use RequestMappingHandlerMapping subclass while still able to inject it using its typename or qualifier
I need to declare custom RequestMappingHandlerMapping and then to autowire it into some service, which seems not possible. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Please suggest me correct way how to do this.
Motivation(feel free to skip): We have rest layer. I would like to have this layer versioned with minimal work over time. I know there are multiple approaches to this, my requirement is, that adding the same endpoint to another version or remove it is at most 1 LOC change. Some endpoints survive to another version, some will be only targeted for one version. I did all this via custom annotation and RequestMappingHandlerMapping, which updates where this method is mapped, so @GetMapping("/whatever") becomes say /rest/v1/whatever and /rest/v2/whatever. But there is a problem with filters(OncePerRequestFilter). Say that you want to exclude some filter for some path; you can do it via net.homecredit.campmgmt.common.filter.CampRestRequestLoggingFilterSupportingExclusions#shouldNotFilter working with jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI but you would have to type in altered URI here, which defies the purpose. We need to do this via annotation, thus having a way, how to bind resolved URIs from RequestMappingHandlerMapping to method they originate from, or better to calculated list of annotations on that method, for speed up. We can do it via: RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandler(HttpServletRequest).getMethod()
The problem: To get the custom RequestMappingHandlerMapping we can use WebMvcRegistrations like this, since if we register it only as a bean, it won't be used:
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Config implements WebMvcRegistrations {

    @Override
    public VersionedRequestMappingHandlerMapping getRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        return new VersionedRequestMappingHandlerMapping(restVersioning());
    }

with this code, spring will create some RequestMappingHandlerMapping, but VersionedRequestMappingHandlerMapping won't be known under that type/name, neither have any qualifier, so I cannot inject it if there are more handlers. And I cannot inject RequestMappingHandlerMapping either, because there are many of them created  for some reason unbeknownst to me. But I need instance of VersionedRequestMappingHandlerMapping (resp. data it creates) for  filter bean mentioned in motivation part above.
I could create VersionedRequestMappingHandlerMapping in such way, that during its process it fills some other bean with discovered data, but that's not a good design. Maybe somehow create 2 instances and scan all controllers twice(not sure if I know how, but it's bad anyways. So not this way either). So far I solved it in a way, that I inject all existing RequestMappingHandlerMapping beans and find the one I want (VersionedRequestMappingHandlerMapping) using instanceof. Not big deal, N instancesof calls during startup, but I'd rather directly inject VersionedRequestMappingHandlerMapping.
Am I overlooking some way how to do that and/or is there something I do principally wrong?
